# Log4j not printing name before message

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a log4j logger that I instantiate like this:

`logger = Logger.getLogger("EQUIP(" + id + ")");`

Doing so, when I call `logger.info("message")`, I should get an output like this (with some date formatting):

`13/11/12 15:08:27 INFO: EQUIP(1): message`

But I'm only getting:

`13/11/12 15:08:27 INFO: message`

I'm also printing `logger.getName()` to the console for debugging and it gives me back the correct "EQUIP(1)" name. This behaviour is happening in some cases in my program, where I have several loggers like this, but mostly in this specific class. I want to know if I'm doing something wrong, if this name should be only the class/package name, or if it can be anything (it works well in 80+% of my loggers). I need to print the ID of each equipment because I have several of them working simultaneous, and tracking them without this would be next to impossible.

How should I fix this, preferably without resourcing to changing all my log calls to include this prefix?

Comment: I think `getLogger` takes the logger name not a prefix.

Comment: Yes, I know, I'm trying to use the prefix as the logger name here, since it doesn't matter if it gets reused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output format depends on the pattern you've configured for the appender.  If the pattern string includes `%c` then you'll get the logger name included, if it doesn't then you won't.

An alternative approach might be to use the [mapped diagnostic context](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html), which is designed to disambiguate between log output from different threads writing to the same logger.